# Jquery code, AJAX form and submit outside the form

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, submit

i don't know what is going wrong with this code:

```
<script language="javascript"> var jdownloader = false; </script>
<script language="javascript" src="http://127.0.0.1:9666/jdcheck.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Interceptamos el evento submit
        if (jdownloader) {
            $('#mysubmit').click(function() {
                $('#form .jdown, #jdown, .jdown').submit(function() {
                    // Enviamos el formulario usando AJAX
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: $(this).attr('action'),
                        data: $(this).serialize(),
                        // Mostramos un mensaje con la respuesta de PHP
                        success: function(data) {
                            $('#result').html(data);
                        }
                    })
                    return false;
                });
            });
        } else {
            $('#mysubmit').click(function() {
                $('#form .jdown, #jdown, .jdown').submit(function() {
                    alert('Abre JDownloader.');
                    return false;
                });
            });
        }
    })
});
</script>
```

And the HTML

```
<form ACTION="http://127.0.0.1:9666/flash/addcrypted2" target="hidden" METHOD="POST" id="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" name="jdown" class="jdown">
    <INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="passwords" VALUE="myPassword"> 
    <INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="source" VALUE="http://jdownloader.org/spielwiese">  
    <INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="jk" VALUE="function f(){ return '31323334353637383930393837363534';}">
    <INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="crypted" VALUE="<?php echo $crypted; ?>">
</form>
<button id="mysubmit">Submit</button>
```

What i'm trying to do it's and ajax POST form that goes weel but when i add

```
 $('#mysubmit').click(function() {

 });
```

to put the submit wherever i want outside the form, don't work.
Any ideas? THANKS! =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an answer for your problems .. :D

try to do like this ..

```
$(function () {
    $('#mysubmit').click(function(){
        if($('form[name=jdown]').submit(function(){return false;})){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: $('form[name=jdown]').attr('action'),
                data: $('form[name=jdown]').serialize(),
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#result').html(data);
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

hopefully help ..

Answer (score 0):

The `.submit(function(){})` does not submit the form, it just sets a callback that should be run when the form is submitted (submit button clicked inside the form for example). Calling `.submit()` (without arguments) then submits the form.

Comment: Is there a form with jquery to submit outside the form? Can you show me please? Thanks